# Radio buttons return to previous selection

Tags: javascript, html

so I want these radio buttons to work like this: When one is selected (after window.confirm) and the confirm is cancelled, to return to the previously selected radio button.

EDIT:

I have a 3 radio buttons, that when you select any of them a confirm box comes up. When the confirm is cancelled, I would like the checked radio button to be the one previous to the new selection.

Comment: I reformatted your code, but is it possible to trim it down to the code you're asking about? It's can be very time consuming to find exactly what your having issues with. And can you expand on what you're having problems with?

Comment: Done, code wasn't really needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**javascript:**

```
var radioVal = "none";
var radioConfirm = '';

function example(e)
{
       if(e.checked == true)
       {
          if(confirm("Is this the value you want to choose?"))
          {
              radioVal = e.value;
              radioConfirm = e;
          }
           else
           {
             radioConfirm.checked = true; 
           }
       }
}
```

**Html:**

```
1 <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:example(this)" value='1' name='test'/>
2 <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:example(this)" value='2' name='test'/>
3 <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:example(this)" value='3' name='test'/>
```

The previous DOM element will be stored when the confirm box has been confirmed(given true back). Whenever you cancel the confirm box, your previous stored DOM element will be selected and checked will be set to true.

If you cancel for the first time there is no previous selection, so you can even check on that:

```
if(!radioConfirm == '')
{
  radioConfirm.checked = true; 
}
else
{
  e.checked = false; 
}
```

This way the check will be unchecked if you haven't confirmed before

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayK3x/3/)**

---

As you see jQuery with answer of @OlivierH it's much easier to use. So it's not a waste to get into that :)

Comment: He also needs to cancel the radio button checking if user clicks no on confirm.

Comment: The OP did not stated this. It's his desire what he wants to do when the confirmation has not been confirmed.

Comment: I quote : "When the confirm is cancelled, I would like the checked radio button to be the one previous to the new selection."

Comment: I've already done that, I want the selected button to return to the previously selected

Comment: Yes! Thanks so much! I do use JQuery, and love it. However it's for a school project and i'm not allowed to.

Comment: I see, hehe. You sure get a better look at how things work with Javascript, so it's sure a great exercise. I suggest you to understand the code first if you use it for school :) Don't forget to accept my answer.

Comment: @nkmol Ok, regarding the "e" part, e isn't defined

Comment: The "e" part is the parameter that is given in the HTML with "this". So make sure the html onclick function is given as showed in my code.

Comment: @nkmol Got it exactly as the example you gave! "e is not defined"

Comment: Too bad you need 20 reputation for chat(Gave you +5 rep, so 3 to go). When does this error occor? it should occur as soon as you click on a radio button. I would like you to create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with my code and the error as i can't reproduce it.

Comment: Great! :) Goodluck further on!

Answer (score 2):

Try `onclick` with return:

```js
var sure = function(s) {
  return confirm('Wana buy:' + s + ' ?');
};
```

```html
<input type='radio' name='item' onclick='return sure(this.value)' value='Apple' checked/>Apple
<input type='radio' name='item' onclick='return sure(this.value)' value='Grape' />Grape
<input type='radio' name='item' onclick='return sure(this.value)' value='Mango' />Mango
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that (with jQuery) :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //global variable to be able to go back to previous checked checkbox 
    //checkbox 1 checked by default
    var $current_chkbox = $('#my_chkbox1');

    $('#my_chkbox1, #my_chkbox2, #my_chkbox3').click(function(){
        // if user confirms, just change the global variable
        if(window.confirm('my message')){
            $current_chkbox = $(this);
        }
        // if he cancel (ie click no), uncheck current checked checkbox and recheck the previous checked one
        else{
            $(this).attr('checked', '');
            $current_chkbox.attr('checked', 'checked');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Take it as a pseudo-code algorithm. Translate it in javascript by your own. You only need a global variable, and to do the same mechanic when you click on a checkbox.

Comment: I'm sorry i dont understand!

Answer (score 1):

**You can use like so -**

```html
<input type="radio" value="1" onclick="return confirmation()" name="collections">
<input type="radio" value="2" onclick="return confirmation()" name="collections">
<input type="radio" value="3" onclick="return confirmation()" name="collections">

<script>
function confirmation(){
 if(confirm("Are you sure!"))
 {
  //do your job
 }
 else
 {
  return false;
 }
}
</script>
```