# Javascript return different selected radio if confirm = cancel

Tags: javascript, perl

I want to be able to select a radio button and a confirmation box pops up. If I press no I want the radio button to return selected to another radio button's value. So lets say I have three buttons one named 1 2 or 3. If I select 1 and then a box comes up and says are you sure? if I press no I want it to revert back to the 3 radio button.

`qq(<input type=radio name=Acceptance value='$rating->{rating}' $checked onclick=confirmation()> $rating->{wording}<br>\n);`

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function confirmation() {
var checked = null;
var inputs = document.getElementsByName('Acceptance');
var answer = confirm ("Are you sure?")
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
          if (inputs[i].checked) {
           checked = inputs[i];
           break;
   }
}
   if(checked!=inputs[1]){
    confirm ("Are you sure?")
    if (console){
    console.log("test");
    }else{
    inputs[1].checked;
    }
}}
```

Comment: btw, `alert` is a built in javascript function - it creates a dialogue box. You probably want to call your function something else. `:)`

Comment: thanks for the tips still working on it but getting closer.

Comment: @ialarmedalien [You should totally drop that and try jQuery.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/234299) Oh, wait...

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I think jQuery has a shallower learning curve (and there are many more resources out there) than plain JS. On the other hand, God kills a cute fluffy creature every time someone uses it, so... `;)`

Comment: What do you mean by "*revert back to the 3 radio button.*"? If the user says 'yes' their checked radio should be/remain checked, and if 'no' the last-checked radio should remain checked?

Comment: yes that is what i mean david

Comment: [Is this helpful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956703/radio-buttons-return-to-previous-selection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clear it use the element's `checked` property and set it to an empty string in order to uncheck your radio buttons. You also need to read the value back from the `confirm()` function if it's false then clear it.

I modified your script slightly to make it work:

```js
function alertUser() {
    var checked = false;
    var element = "";
    var inputs = document.getElementsByName('Acceptance');
    
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].checked) {
            checked = true;
            element = inputs[i];
            break;
        }
    }
  
    if (checked == true) {
        if (!confirm('You have chosen ' + element.value + ' is this correct?')) {
            element.checked = "";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type='radio' name='Acceptance' value='option1' checked='checked' onclick='alertUser()'>option 1
<br/>
<input type='radio' name='Acceptance' value='option2' onclick='alertUser()'>option 2
<br/>
<input type='radio' name='Acceptance' value='option3' onclick='alertUser()'>option 3
<br/>
```

Comment: Btw I changed the name of your function to "alertUser" in my example because alert() is a built-in function and unless there is a need for it it should not be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

My own approach, using the native `confirm()`, would be:

```
function checkConfirm() {
    // get the user's response ('ok' is true, 'cancel' is false):
    var choice = confirm ('Are you sure?'),
    // find the previously-checked element from the same radio group (if any):
        previousChoice = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"][name="' + this.name + '"].userChecked');

    // if the user clicked 'ok' (true):
    if (choice) {
        // we remove the 'userChecked' class from the previously-checked radio:
        previousChoice.classList.remove('userChecked');
        // and add that class to the current element:
        this.classList.add('userChecked');
        // because the 'change' event fires *after* the radio is checked,
        // we can let the browser deal with that
    }
    // the user clicked 'cancel' (false):
    else {
        // uncheck the radio:
        this.checked = false;
        // if there was a previously-checked element:
        if (previousChoice) {
            // we re-check it:
            previousChoice.checked = true;
        }
    }
}

// iterate over the elements in the collection returned by document.querySelectorAll():
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]'), function(radio){
    // the 'radio' variable is the radio element, and we add a change-event
    // handler (defined above):
    radio.addEventListener('change', checkConfirm);
});
```

```js
function checkConfirm() {
  var choice = confirm('Are you sure?'),
    previousChoice = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"][name="' + this.name + '"].userChecked');
  if (choice) {
    previousChoice.classList.remove('userChecked');
    this.classList.add('userChecked');
  } else {
    this.checked = false;
    if (previousChoice) {
      previousChoice.checked = true;
    }
  }
}

[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]'), function(radio) {
  radio.addEventListener('change', checkConfirm);
});
```

```html
<form action="">
  <fieldset>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="demo" />Input 1</label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="demo" />Input 2</label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="demo" />Input 3</label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

References:

- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).
- [`Window.confirm()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.confirm).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to revert back to a specific element. Instead of clearing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function alertUser() {
    var checked = false;
    var element = "";
    var inputs = document.getElementsByName('Acceptance');
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
          if (inputs[i].checked) {
           checked = true;
           element = inputs[i];
           break;
          }
        }   
    if(checked==true){
        if (!confirm('You have chosen '+ element.value + ' is this correct?')){
           inputs[1].checked=true;
        };
    };
   }
</script>
```